# How do I add a Windows host to a Zabbix configuration?

Tags: windows, zabbix

I have downloaded and started the Zabbix appliance (running as a VirtualBox guest on a Fedora host) , and it works fine. I have also downloaded and installed the Zabbix Agent 2 on my Windows (running as a VirtualBox guest on that same Fedora host).

I set the following settings in the agent config file:

```
Server=192.168.3.147
ServerActive=192.168.3.147
```

and started the Zabbix agent.

Then, I created a host in the Zabbix dashboard, using "Agent" and putting the IP address of the Windows machine (192.168.3.225) in:

[image]

But, nothing really happens.

What do I have to do to monitor that Windows machine in the Zabbix appliance?

Comment: Is the port 10050 opened on the Widows machine? Is inbound connections allowed on port 10050 on windows firewall?

Comment: Also set Templates to `Windows by Zabbix agent`.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes. When connecting to the machine with `nc`, it makes the  connection, which also shows up in the Zabbix agent's log.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks, that seems to have worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set a template that will be used to connect the agent to the server. Your image shiws that it's not set yet. Set Templates to `Windows by Zabbix agent`.

If/when everything is set properly but you still can't connect, check that the port is opened and not blocked by the firewall.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. After setting the template, I got an error it couldn't connect, but this was fixed easily by changing a small setting in the virtual networking.